# Passing JSON Values Into POST Request - Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api

I have the following index.js file;

```
var Lob = require('lob')('test_6afa806011ecd05b39535093f7e57757695');

var residence = require('./addresses.json');

console.log(residence.residence.length);

for (i = 0; i < residence.residence.length; i++) {
    console.log(residence.residence[i].name);

    Lob.addresses.create({
        name: 'residence.residence[i].name',
    }, function(err, res) {
        console.log(err, res);
    });
}
```

When I `console.log( residence.residence[i].name )`, the appropriate response "RESIDENT" appears.

However, I'm trying to pass in that same value as a value in the post request under `Lob.addresses.create({` which isn't recognizing it.

How do I pass in that value into my key value pair as the value for "name:"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are passing in a literal String 'residence.residence[i].name' because of your use of quotes... Drop the quotes:

```
for (i = 0; i < residence.residence.length; i++) {
    console.log(residence.residence[i].name);

    Lob.addresses.create({
        name: residence.residence[i].name,
    }, function(err, res) {
        console.log(err, res);
    });

}
```